# How to execute function only after getting all data from REST Api

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, onload, canvasjs

I need to draw a chart of 12 month . The data of each month i get from the rest api.
so this i what i do

```
$.getJSON(link, function(data){
  // store data in a variable
}
x 12 times to get 12 variable

window.onload = function(){
  // draw chart using CanvasJS, using 12 variable above 
}
```

but what i get is some point ( some month ) the rest api take quite long time to get the data--> the chart will draw with undefined value --> There is some months in the graph there will be no point.

Anyone suggest how to fix this ??

Comment: You will probably want to use promises for this.

Comment: Just put your draw logic inside the `getJSON` success callback.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're making 12 different API calls, and you want to assemble the canvas once everything has completed.

You will want to make the individual calls and store them in an array called `promises`.

```
var promise1 = $.getJSON(link);
//... x 12
var promises = [promise1, promise2, promise3, //..etc];
```

Then you will use `$.when` to wait for them all to resolve.

```
$.when.apply($, promises).then(function(allMyData) {
     //make my canvas here
}, function(e) {
     console.log("My ajax failed");
});
```

All of the data you would normally retrieve in your AJAX callback should now be accessible as `allMyData`, an array of each response.

Comment: can you say more about the allMyData variable, how to use it im quite confused

Comment: `$.getJSON(link, function(data){}`. The `data` variable in this callback, when you use `$.when.apply` on the array of `$.getJSON(link);` calls becomes an element of the `allMyData` array.

Comment: So the `allMyData` result for `[promise1, promise2, promise3, //..etc];` would be `[data1, data2, data3, ..etc]`

Answer (score 0):

Set two variables to record data number change, and check if the number of stored data is matching the data number you need, if so, draw the chart.

```
var totalDataNumber = 12;
var storedDataNumber = 0;

$.getJSON(link, function(data){
  // store data in a variable
  storedDataNumber++;
  // check if all data are ready
  if (storedDataNumber === totalDataNumber) {
    draw();
  }
}
// x 12 times to get 12 variable

function draw() {

  // draw chart using CanvasJS, using 12 variable above 
}
```